# Issues with bundle install

Tags: rubygems

Bundler::PermissionError: There was an error while trying to write to `/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/cache/rake-13.1.0.gem`. It is
likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.

Updating nvm
Retrying download gem from https://rubygems.org/ due to error (2/4): Bundler::PermissionError There was an error while trying to write to `/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/cache/rake-13.1.0.gem`. It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.